# How to get country name in php with geoplugin?

Tags: php, mysql, geolocation, ip

Hello I am getting stuck on this I don't know whats happening. I am using google geo plugin api for getting country name using IP address. Here is my code below:-

```
$client  = @$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
$forward = @$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
$remote  = @$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$result  = array('country'=>'', 'city'=>'');
if(filter_var($client, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP)){
    $ip = $client;
}elseif(filter_var($forward, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP)){
    $ip = $forward;
}else{
    $ip = $remote;
}
$ip_data = @json_decode(file_get_contents("http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp?ip=".$ip));    
if($ip_data && $ip_data->geoplugin_countryName != null){
    $result['country'] = $ip_data->geoplugin_countryCode;
    $result['city'] = $ip_data->geoplugin_city;
}
echo "<pre>"; print_r($result); die;
```

I am from India. Sometime when I access the website its showing India or sometime its showing Singapore. But I am located in India only. Can anyone suggest us what I am doing wrong and provide some alternative so we can get right results.

Comment: If you echo out your 3 ip's would any of them be from Singapore?

Comment: My be firewall or Proxy setting or may be any VPN extension in your browser causing the issue

Comment: @Joseph_J i have tested dummy ips from diffrenet country  its working fine but when we do with actual one its nor working

Comment: @AlivetoDie when we access website in canada its not showing country name

Comment: That really did not answer my question.  Echo out your client, forward, and remote ip's.  It might provide a clue as to what your getting from the server.  Might help you trouble shoot.  Just putting in a known ip's is not the same thing.

Comment: yes i already echo at my client system in canada its not showing any country name its empty results coming @Joseph_J

Comment: what is the ip you are getting from the canada request??

Comment: echo out your $client, $forward, & $remote values!

Comment: $remote value is echoing but $client, $forward are not echoing :( @Joseph_J

Comment: Now we know that the problem is with the IP's that the server is giving you.  I am probably not going to be able to help you with that.  It has nothing to do with the geoplugin.  I would delete this question and repost a new one relating to why you are not getting IP results from server.

Answer (score 1):

It could be because of the you are retrieving the ip. You can get clients's ip address using:

```
function get_client_ip() {
$ipaddress = '';
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']))
    $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
else if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))
    $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
else if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED']))
    $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED'];
else if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR']))
    $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'];
else if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED']))
    $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED'];
else if(isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']))
    $ipaddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
else
    $ipaddress = 'UNKNOWN';
return $ipaddress;
}
```

and then find the country name using the ip that u received :

```
function ip_info($ip = NULL, $purpose = "location", $deep_detect = TRUE) {
$output = NULL;
if (filter_var($ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP) === FALSE) {
    $ip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
    if ($deep_detect) {
        if (filter_var(@$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'], FILTER_VALIDATE_IP))
            $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
        if (filter_var(@$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'], FILTER_VALIDATE_IP))
            $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    }
}
$purpose    = str_replace(array("name", "\n", "\t", " ", "-", "_"), NULL, strtolower(trim($purpose)));
$support    = array("country", "countrycode", "state", "region", "city", "location", "address");
$continents = array(
    "AF" => "Africa",
    "AN" => "Antarctica",
    "AS" => "Asia",
    "EU" => "Europe",
    "OC" => "Australia (Oceania)",
    "NA" => "North America",
    "SA" => "South America"
);
if (filter_var($ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP) && in_array($purpose, $support)) {
    $ipdat = @json_decode(file_get_contents("http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp?ip=" . $ip));
    if (@strlen(trim($ipdat->geoplugin_countryCode)) == 2) {
        switch ($purpose) {
            case "location":
                $output = array(
                    "city"           => @$ipdat->geoplugin_city,
                    "state"          => @$ipdat->geoplugin_regionName,
                    "country"        => @$ipdat->geoplugin_countryName,
                    "country_code"   => @$ipdat->geoplugin_countryCode,
                    "continent"      => @$continents[strtoupper($ipdat->geoplugin_continentCode)],
                    "continent_code" => @$ipdat->geoplugin_continentCode
                );
                break;
            case "address":
                $address = array($ipdat->geoplugin_countryName);
                if (@strlen($ipdat->geoplugin_regionName) >= 1)
                    $address[] = $ipdat->geoplugin_regionName;
                if (@strlen($ipdat->geoplugin_city) >= 1)
                    $address[] = $ipdat->geoplugin_city;
                $output = implode(", ", array_reverse($address));
                break;
            case "city":
                $output = @$ipdat->geoplugin_city;
                break;
            case "state":
                $output = @$ipdat->geoplugin_regionName;
                break;
            case "region":
                $output = @$ipdat->geoplugin_regionName;
                break;
            case "country":
                $output = @$ipdat->geoplugin_countryName;
                break;
            case "countrycode":
                $output = @$ipdat->geoplugin_countryCode;
                break;
        }
    }
}
return $output;

}
```

There would be times that you won't get the clients ip using the function that i have mentioned before, in that case just like you have used you can get their public ip using:

```
file_get_contents("http://ipecho.net/plain")
```

and again call the ip_info function with the public ip that you have received.

Comment: Please add an explanation along with the code, it will make the answer much more useful. Stack Overflow isn't about users copy-pasting code-snippets, even if they do work perfectly.